# Line break in math environment

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I've typed this: `$A,A+k,A+2k,\ldots,A+nk,B$, kde $k$ je \textit{krok}` and the line breaks in the middle of `A+2k`. Is it OK or should I break the line manually before this expression?

Answer (score 1):

Keep those symbols separated:

```
$A$, $A+k$, $A+2k$,~\dots, $A+nk$, $B$ kde $k$ je \textit{krok}
```

and you'll probably get a better line break.

If still the break is undesirable, then something like

```
$A$, $A+k$, $A+\nobreak 2k$,~\dots, $A+nk$, $B$ kde $k$ je \textit{krok}
```

will make TeX choose a different break point. However I'd prefer a break in the middle of `$A+2k$` to an underfull line (or an overfull one, of course).

Work on these aspects only during the final revision, when no more changes to the text are planned.

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: @user32680 `$A+\nobreak 2k$` should do. Work on these aspects only at the final (no more changes, really) revision.

Comment: It did the break in the middle of 'A+k', so still the same problem. The problem I want to solve is if it is "typographically" bad solution.

Comment: @user32680 Add `\nobreak` also in `$A+\nobreak k$`. It's not bad typography, *per se*; some compromise between the ideal world and the reality of line length must be made. Try some `\nobreak`, change the wording: there are several possibilities; but, most importantly, wait till the document is in final form. Don't waste time in fixing something that a subsequent change in the document might make not a problem any more.